# Super Micro Model 827-16 -> CentOS 6 RAID Controller driver

Tags: linux, centos, raid, intel, supermicro

I have a Super Micro model 827-16 (part no: 6027TR-HTRF+) and need to get CentOS 6 installed. The problem is that I haven't been able to confirm if there are CentOS specific/supported RAID drivers available.

Super Micro's site only has 3 options, if you choose RedHat, which are: - VGA - LAN - ALL

The C600 is not hardware RAID, so I'm just making sure that I have the best possible configurations to achieve the best performance and stability.

Does anyone have any recommendations for me?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it? As you have the server already what's stopping you? You phrase this as if it's a hypothetical problem that would easily be tested yourself.

Also, Red Hat 6 is in the [OS certification matrix](http://www.supermicro.com/support/resources/OS/OS_Certification_Intel.cfm?MProduct_Name=SYS-6027TR-HTRF), so there is no reason that CentOS 6 wouldn't work.

Comment: I'm asking because I've been reading up on software RAIDs and I'm getting mixed reviews. This server needs to go into production and it's basically going to be slammed by requests an db writes/reads all day.

I just want to make sure that I do everything possible to get the best configuration, which is why I reach out to the community of professionals.